# Origin of Buchowski's paradox

Tags: pragmatics, adjectives

According to [Wolfram Math World](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BuchowskiParadox.html), Buchowski's paradox concerns the use of comparative adjectives in apparently paradoxical statements such as "My younger brother is older than me" (possible if the speaker has two older brothers).

Who is Buchowski? Has the paradox been discussed in any depth in a publication, or was it just an offhand observation?

Comment: Interestingly I have searched for this paradox for a long time, I couldn't find anything other than one sentence explanations either. no reference, citations etc.